# How to get the same result with PHP and CryptoJS using SHA256?

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, cryptojs

I'm trying to decode Firefox Sync data using javascript, porting one php library which does it (https://github.com/mikerowehl/firefox-sync-client-php). The idea is to decode sync data without sending sync key to the server. This is just context, the problem I have is much more specific.

One portion of code requires using sha256 to obtain certain key. I would like to replicate it in javascript. The approach I've tried, with CryptoJS, is this:

PHP code:

```
$key = hash_hmac("sha256",'OLA K ASE','CLAVE', false);
print $key;
```

Equivalent Javascript code (previously, I've included http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js):

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("OLA K ASE", "CLAVE");
console.log(hash.toString());
```

This works fine. In each case, output is 9591d44df0c8e2d7a1f400f41117c536e10f58d7e28bdc1cad9d81e70290bc1b, which I suppose is correct.

But, when I'm trying to encode non-ascii strings, results differ. For example, with this PHP code:

```
function hexstring($str){
    return preg_replace('/\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/e', 'chr(hexdec(\'$1\'))', $str);
}
$text = hexstring('\x00\x44\xb0\x2c\x0b');
$key = hexstring('\xd6\xf8\xb0\x2c\x0b');
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256",$text,$key, false);
print $hash;
```

I get `0697f5528c996006ffeb09b9130bf8e9056563245656d405e233bcafdbffb645`. But with the 'equivalent' javascript code:

```
var text = "\x00\x44\xb0\x2c\x0b";
var key = "\xd6\xf8\xb0\x2c\x0b";
hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text,key);
console.log(hash.toString());
```

I get `13c983b69f82c277815c03d13e90b1ec1e9cbca2b6912ad1f8224f3de8b82130`, a different value.

I thought it could be caused by non-ascii character, so I did a quick test:

```
$text = '';
for($i = 0;$i < 10; $i++){
    $text .= chr($i);
}
$key = '';
for($i = 0;$i < 10; $i++){
    $key .= chr($i*2);
}
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256",$text,$key, false);
print $hash;
```

And, javascript equivalent:

```
var text = '';
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    text += String.fromCharCode(i);
}
var key = '';
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    key += String.fromCharCode(i*2);
}
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key);
console.log(hash.toString());
```

In both cases, output is `c5d7adbbabcec5416c6b7a1f01e17e42d95a529f5bcc805d9b04b93f33994c9d`.

This is a big WTF? for me. Could somebody give me a piece of advice of how to continue with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It was a problem with character codes. Instead of this:

```
var text = "\x00\x44\xb0\x2c\x0b";
var key = "\xd6\xf8\xb0\x2c\x0b";
hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text,key);
```

I should indicate CryptoJS that they were Latin-1 encoded strings:

```
var text = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("\x00\x44\xb0\x2c\x0b");
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("\xd6\xf8\xb0\x2c\x0b");
hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text,key);
```

I don't know clearly why is this happening, so if somebody could explain it with a little bit of detail it would be great.

Comment: You could consider using base64_encode() on the data to avoid the character set issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$text = "\x00\x44\xb0\x2c\x0b";
$key = "\xd6\xf8\xb0\x2c\x0b";
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256",$text,$key, false);
print $hash;
```

It's proabably because the preg_* functions have a problem with these special characters.
And PHP supports \x12 hex-encoding without any function.

Comment: Thanks, Aragon0, but same problem. I added preg function only for you to have a simpler example: the string building process was too much complex and only the hashing process was relevant. 

btw, thanks for the hex-encoding clue, didn't knew that.